# Regex para extraer ciertos valores númericos

Tags: python, regex

Estoy tratando de parsear lineas de este tipo con expresiones regulares en python :

```
21698213.20307                  -4937213.445 7  -3801759.02548  21698206.56648
```

Estos valores se refieren en concreto a "observaciones" de señales GPS.
En la línea anterior habría 5 "observaciones". Si los observables son `L1, L2, C1, C2, P2` los valores que me gustaría extraer :

```
L1 : { observación -> 21698213.203, LossOfLockInd -> 0, SignalStrengthInd -> 7}

L2 : { observación -> NOHAY, LossOfLockInd -> NOHAY, SignalStrengthInd -> NOHAY }

C1 : { observación -> -4937213.445, LossOfLockInd -> 0 (NO HAY), SignalStrengthInd -> 7}

C2 : { observación -> -3801759.025, LossOfLockInd -> 4, SignalStrengthInd -> 8}

P2 : { observación -> 21698206.566, LossOfLockInd -> 4, SignalStrengthInd -> 8}
```

Es decir necesito extraer cada "número decimal de 3 decimales(**observación**)" y "cada número individual o espacio (**LossOfLock, SignalStrength**)". En el caso de que no haya valor para uno de los observables me gustaría tener 3 elementos vacíos (Si no hay observable la separación entre cada uno de los observables es 18)

De momento he sido capaz de obtener los decimales y los enteros por separado, pero no logro unir también los espacios vacíos(**LossOfLock**) ni separar en 3 elementos vacíos los observables que faltan.

Esta es la expresión que estoy usando de momento.

```
([-+]?\d*\.\d{3}|\d)
```

Ejemplo de captura que hace hasta el momento:

```js
var match = '21698213.20307                  -4937213.445 7  -3801759.02548  21698206.56648'.match(/([-+]?\d*\.\d{3}|\d)/g);
console.log(match);
```

Al final usé la expresión regular :  `([-+ \d]{9}[. ][ \d]{3})([\d ])([\d ])` propuesta por **Mariano** y un par de retoques a base de código para rellenar los huecos que el regex deja al final :

```
##Obtenemos la observación
the_obs = re.findall(self.REGEX_PARSE_LINEA_OBS, ''.join(obsArray[obsindex : obsindex + step]) )
## quitamos los espacios de la lista
## El regex devuelve un array de tuplas
## con chain.from_iterable() las tuplas desaparecen 
## y pasan dentro de la lista como strings
the_obs = map(strip_, list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(the_obs)))

## El regex nos puede dejar hiuecos al final si no hay observaciones
## con esto rellenamos los huecos
if(len(the_obs) < len(self.header['OBSERV_TYPES'] * 3)) : 
    ## Cuantos huecos faltan por rellenar ?
    size = (len(self.header['OBSERV_TYPES'] * 3)) - len(the_obs)
    ## rellenamos los huecos DEL FINAL!!!
    the_obs[len(the_obs):] = ['' for x in range(size)]
```

Comment: Alomejor no me expliqué bien, si cogemos el primer "valor" : `21698213.20307` . De todo esto `21698213.203` esto sería el valor de la señal. `0` y `7` serían otras variables. El siguiente "valor" son espacios en blanco por lo tanto no hay. Y el "tercer" elemento es un poco distinto ya que en vez de tener el 0 de antes tiene un espacio, pero ese valor debe ser un 0 y también debería "seleccionarlo". Gracias por el feddback!

Comment: El cuarto elemento, ¿no podría tener más dígitos? Por ejemplo, en vez de `7` que sea `123` ... ¿Y podría haber un elemento que sea `-.321`?

Comment: No, siempre va a ser un número entre 0 y 9. Respecto a lo del `-.321` creo que no.

Comment: Si sirve de algo este es el tipo de fichero que estoy parseando :  http://gage14.upc.es/gLAB/HTML/Observation_Rinex_v2.11.html, las obsservaciones empiezan después del "END OF HEADER"

Comment: El problema es que pueden haber más de 5 observables según el fichero. Y tampoco sabría que observable es el que ese satélite no ha leído. Pero se agradece el esfuerzo!!

Comment: Creo que esta expresión me puede servir ya que a parte también captura los espacios en blanco : `([-+]?\d*\.\d{3}|[ \s]{1,}|\d)`

Comment: El número de observables no es fijo siempre, se especifica e n la cabecera. Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que te refieres? Ten en cuenta que puede que haya observables vacíos para una época determinada. Saludos y gracias de nuevo!! =)

Comment: Me refiero a que al tener un ancho fijo, es siempre 1 espacio (separador), 9 `[- \d]` (parte entera), 1 `[ .]` (punto), 3 decimales, 1 loss, y 1 signal --> https://regex101.com/r/uSe2Ne/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo que [el texto original](http://gage14.upc.es/gLAB/HTML/Observation_Rinex_v2.11.html) tiene un ancho fijo para cada elemento, en vez de usar una expresión regular, recomendaría recuperar cada valor según la posición en la que se encuentra.

Un ejemplo simplificado para el punto planteado sería:

```python
datos = r"""
  21698213.20307                  -4937213.445 7  -3801759.02548  21698206.56648
 121367582.20508  94572134.49208  23095489.677 9  23095481.949 9  23095483.463 7
        42.000          40.000                                                  
 134357446.85408                                                  23095483.463 7
"""

#Los anchos de cada columna
# Separador: 1; Observable: 13; LossOfLock: 1; SignalStrength: 1
columnas = [1,13,1,1]

for linea in datos.splitlines(): #cada línea
    for inicio in range(0, len(linea), sum(columnas)): #cada elemento
        for columna in columnas: #cada valor de la columna dentro del elemento
            print(linea[inicio:inicio+columna])
            inicio += columna
```

Resultado:

```
　
 21698213.203
0
7





 -4937213.445

7

 -3801759.025
4
8
```

```python
# etc...
```

Demo:

<kbd>[Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Zub2pE)</kbd>

---

Si aún así, te interesa seguir probando con expresiones regulares, usaría la misma lógica: obtener siempre el elemento con ancho fijo. Eso sí, podemos usar grupos para separar *el valor de cada columna*.

```
r' ([-+ \d]{9}[. ][ \d]{3})([\d ])([\d ])'
```

Ejemplo:

```
datos = r""" 121367582.20508  94572134.49208  23095489.677 9  23095481.949 9  23095483.463 7
        42.000          40.000                                                  
 134357446.85408                                                                """

resultado = re.findall(r' ([-+ \d]{9}[. ][ \d]{3})([\d ])([\d ])', datos)

print(resultado)
```

Resultado

```
[('121367582.205', '0', '8'), (' 94572134.492', '0', '8'), (' 23095489.677', ' ', '9'), (' 23095481.949', ' ', '9'), (' 23095483.463', ' ', '7'), ('       42.000', ' ', ' '), ('       40.000', ' ', ' '), ('             ', ' ', ' '), ('             ', ' ', ' '), ('             ', ' ', ' '), ('134357446.854', '0', '8'), ('             ', ' ', ' '), ('             ', ' ', ' '), ('             ', ' ', ' '), ('             ', ' ', ' ')]
```

Demo:

<kbd>[rextester.com](http://rextester.com/XWN12812)</kbd>

Comment: Buenas! Disculpa el retraso, la verdad es que es el resultado que busco. Creo que estaba tan empeñado en haerlo con expresiones regulares que no barajé lo sencillo que sería sin utilizarlas. Gracias!!

Comment: También me pasa muchas veces, pero Python tiene [varias limitaciones](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-python.html) en `re` que algunas veces te llevan a buscar la forma estándar.

Comment: También es que estoy metiéndome ahora en el mundo de los regex (del cual soy un auténtico ignorante) y quería probar. Así que nada, iré preparando tazas de café. jjajaa Saludos y gracias por todo!! =)

Comment: Al final me decanté por la opción del regex, ya que el código me quedaba much omás limpio, el único problema de tu regex es que los observables vacíos al final no los coge. Algo que he solventado facilmente añadiendo los espacios necesarios. Dejo lo que he hecho en la pregunta. En este caso concreto que sería más efeciente, usar regex o varios bucles? Saludos!! =)

Comment: Disculpa, no es culpa del regex efectivamente si no del fichero, que directamente no tiene esos espacios en los "huecos" donde no hay observables, no sé si me explico. En los huecos entre observable y observable si. De todas formas se solventa facilmente como he dicho. Muchas gracias de nuevo!! =)

Comment: De nada.. Algo a tener en cuenta: yo había revisado el [enlace que compartiste](http://gage14.upc.es/gLAB/HTML/Observation_Rinex_v2.11.html) y tenía todos los espacios... Lo obtuve yendo a la página y escribiendo esto en la consola: `document.body.innerText.match(/END OF HEADER *\n(?:.*\n){2}([\s\S]*)\s*10\s+3\s+5/)[1]` .. ¿Habrás perdido los espacios en otro lado?

Comment: No, lo he comprobado del fichero que tengo original. El enlace es simplemente un ejemplo de fichero para saber qué es cada cosa. En mi fichero no hay espacios cuando no hay observables al final =@@ jajaja Saludos!! =)